# Eigen - Balancing matrix for eigenvalue

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

My experience (like some others: [How do I get specified Eigenvectors from the generalized Schur factorization of a matrix pair using LAPACK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912310/how-do-i-get-specified-eigenvectors-from-the-generalized-schur-factorization-of)) is that the eigenvalues obtained from Eigen (I don't care about the eigenvectors) are not nearly as reliable as those obtained from numpy, matlab, etc. when the matrix is ill-conditioned.

The internet (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/balance.html) suggests that balancing is the solution, but I can't figure out how to do this in Eigen.  Can anyone help?

At the moment I have an annoying two-layer solution that involves python and C++ and I would like to push everything into C++; the eigenvalue solver is the only part that is holding me back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, this fantastic little paper on arxiv gives a nice clear description of balancing: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.5766.pdf.  When I implement this balancing, the eigenvalues agree almost perfectly with numpy.  It would be great if Eigen would balance the matrix prior to taking eigenvalues.

```
void balance_matrix(const Eigen::MatrixXd &A, Eigen::MatrixXd &Aprime, Eigen::MatrixXd &D) {
    // https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.5766.pdf (Algorithm #3)
    const int p = 2;
    double beta = 2; // Radix base (2?)
    Aprime = A;
    D = Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(A.rows(), A.cols());
    bool converged = false;
    do {
        converged = true;
        for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < A.rows(); ++i) {
            double c = Aprime.col(i).lpNorm<p>();
            double r = Aprime.row(i).lpNorm<p>();
            double s = pow(c, p) + pow(r, p);
            double f = 1;
            while (c < r / beta) {
                c *= beta;
                r /= beta;
                f *= beta;
            }
            while (c >= r*beta) {
                c /= beta;
                r *= beta;
                f /= beta;
            }
            if (pow(c, p) + pow(r, p) < 0.95*s) {
                converged = false;
                D(i, i) *= f;
                Aprime.col(i) *= f;
                Aprime.row(i) /= f;
            }
        }
    } while (!converged);
}
```

Comment: I'm not using `Eigen`, but this helped me (too). +1.